# Controller problem with header's data with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

so here's my problem.
I'm trying to have dynamic data in my header. It's supposed to represent the number of items a user has in his cart.
So here's my header (the header is a fragment that I included in the layout.html) and the data is in the last li

```
<nav >
            <ul>
                <li><a th:href="@{/index}" class="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/products/list}" class="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/admin/index}" class="">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/login}" class="">Login</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{/user-page}" class="">User</a></li>
                <li>
                    <p th:text="${cart.id}"></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

But since the header is available on every page of the web app, what should I do (in the controllers) to get this data?
I tried to put the cart data in the IndexController but it doesn't work. I'm not comfortable with Spring and Thymeleaf so I might be doing something wrong or maybe I missed something on data binding. I only have once constraint, I don't want to use Ajax or Jquery. Unless I have no choice but I doubt that. Here's what I tried in the IndexController

```
@GetMapping({"/", "/index", "/home"})
    public String getIndex(Model model) {
        this.userCart.setId(5);
        this.userCart.setNumberItems(11);
        model.addAttribute("cart", userCart);
        model.addAttribute("phrase", "Oui oui si si 92izi");
        model.addAttribute("nbItems", "10");
        return "index";
    }
```

I also tried to make another method mapped to "/" but it causes an error since I can't have to methods mapped to the same url. So what am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a model attribute application wide, then you can use an `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {
  
  @ModelAttribute("numberOfItemsInCart")
  public int getNumberOfItemsInCart() {
    // get the cart and return the number of items
  }

}
```

And use this attribute in your template:

```
<p th:text="${numberOfItemsInCart}"></p>
```

The method that is annotated with `@ModelAttribute` can also declare `HttpServletRequest request` as a parameter if needed (See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments for all possible arguments for the method).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice for more details about `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: It's not really that I need this attribute application wide. I just need the header to update whenever the user's cart data changes in the server side.£
Something like that but with Thymeleaf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQIWt8830Z8

Comment: If you want dynamic updates to the HTML, then you need to use JavaScript. Thymeleaf renders on the server and sends the resulting HTML to the browser.